# Django 1.5.1 login_required decorator not catching unauthenticated users

Tags: python, django, login-required

I have a very typical view/login_required decorator implementation, and it's been reported to me that sometimes as often as twice a day, the QA team will run across this error:

```
ERROR: AttributeError at /plan/reviewplan/1702/ 'WSGIRequest' object has no 
attribute 'user' Request Method: GET Request URL: 
http://<ip>/plan/reviewplan/1702/ Django Version: 1.5.1

Traceback: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 187. 
response = middleware_method(request, response) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/template.py" in process_response 118. pformat(k(self.request))) for k in get_standard_processors() 
File "/opt/ion/iondb/rundb/context_processors.py" in base_context_processor 25. 
if request.user: Exception Type: AttributeError at /plan/reviewplan/1702/ 
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I checked and the view does in fact have a login_required decorator.  It's also been reported on other views which are decorated with login_required as well.

The return on the views is:

```
return render_to_response("template.html", context_instance=ctx, mimetype="text/html")
```

FYI:  The ctx instance is stored in the session, and often updated between view calls.  I inherited this design and I can't do anything about it.  The function that handles this is:

```
def _create_context_from_session(request, next_step_name):
    ctxd = request.session['saved_plan']
    ctxd['helper'] = request.session['plan_step_helper']
    ctxd['step'] = None
    if next_step_name in ctxd['helper'].steps:
        ctxd['step'] = ctxd['helper'].steps[next_step_name]
    context = RequestContext(request, ctxd)
    return context
```

Comment: What are your values for `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`? Do you encounter similar problems if you disable the django debug toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the context variables stored in the session have an old request instance stored (without user attribute)? Maybe modify returned context to include current request, something like this:

```
def _create_context_from_session(request, next_step_name):
    ctxd = request.session['saved_plan']
    ctxd['request'] = request  # Add this line.
    ...
```

Do You have the `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

It seems also, that you have debug toolbar enabled. Does the problem exists when you disable debug toolbar?

**Also:**

Debug toolbar is executing template context processors in it's middleware and one of your context processors tries to access `request.user`.

Can you modify the line mentioned in this traceback:

```
File "/opt/ion/iondb/rundb/context_processors.py" in base_context_processor 25. 
if request.user: Exception Type: AttributeError at /plan/reviewplan/1702/
```

Instead of `if request.user:` do `if hasattr(request, 'user'):` in the `/opt/ion/iondb/rundb/context_processors.py` file.

Does the `"/opt/ion/iondb/rundb/context_processors.py"` context processor is executed after `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"`? Order of execution of context processors is defined by the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Comment: The request instance that's passed to the _create_context_form_session is the request variable that's passed to the view function, and is never stored in the session.  Also, why would the debug toolbar affect the request.user?  And yes "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth is added in settings.py.

Comment: Edited my answer, maybe this time will be more helpful.

Comment: 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' is the first in the list, followed by 'django.core.context_processors.request', and further down is the custom one.